# jquery balloon moving effect

Tags: jquery, html, css

i want an image move smoothly inside a div using jquery and css.I have checked rotation and animation.but nothing worked as the way i need.

```
<div class="baloon" style="position:fixed;left:0px;top:160px;">
<img id="rot" class="rotate1" src="http://artinnmedia.com/images/baloon5.png">
</div>
```

check this http://artinnmedia.com/ ...the balloon have to move smoothly in two directions inside that div

please anyone help me to solve this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for a float effect. This is actually just moving up to point A and down to point B. You can reproduce this with `transform:translateY();`:

```
#rot
{
    position: absolute;
    
    -webkit-animation: Floatingy 3s infinite ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes Floatingy {
    from {
        -webkit-transform:translateY(0px);
    }
    65% {
        -webkit-transform:translateY(15px);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-0px);
    }
}
```

I use `ease-in-out` so it will slowly reduce speed for every point.

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VCM8k/3)

Comment: how can i make move sidewise also

Comment: use [`transform:translateX();`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp) for this. You might as well use the transform shorthand `transform:translate(x, y);` [example](http://jsfiddle.net/VCM8k/10/)

Comment: @nkmol  I noticed a problem now...that the code is not working in firefox or internet explorer .It is working fine in google crome

Comment: @Chinthu I'm sorry, i should have clarified this. But chrome and safari are supporting `-webkit-`, FF and IE aren't. You can just use the same code without the `-webkit-`. Look here : http://jsfiddle.net/VCM8k/14/ Hope this helped :)

Comment: @Chinthu What version of FF are you using? Version 15 and below does need the prefix `-moz-`. http://caniuse.com/css-animation

Comment: @nkmol I am using  firefox 25.0.1 this link http://jsfiddle.net/VCM8k/15/ is not showing image in my firefox

Comment: @Chinthu You did not use `-webkit-animation` in your example. add `-webkit-animation: Floatingy 3s infinite ease-in-out;`. Also it should just work fine for Firefox, i'm also using version 25.0